# Draw ellipse based on values within an attribute table

Tags: area, contour, footprint, ellipse

I would like to be able to draw and ellipse on a map based on values within an attributes table. At the moment I have 6 transects at a site with values based on IQI (Infaunal Quality Index) values; these values are used to determine a footprint on the seabed.

I have an attribute table with 6 transects with points along those transects with a know IQI value based invertebrates identified from a sample.
From these values we have generated an IQI value on an S curve (EXCEL) that is demened an exceptable area of effect. From this S curve I have added a line within the attributes table for this value and its distance, where I would like the ellipse boarder to fall.

I was hoping to do it based on an interpolated raster layer, then generate a contour layer and use those contours to generate a polygon based on that contour value, but this just gives individual contours around each transect, rather than what I would like, which is a contour around the whole site.

My other solution was create another layer with manually drawn line features along the transect based on the S curve value then physically draw an ellipse based on these lines. This doesn't seem like the most accurate solution.

Does anyone out there know of a tool that will do this?

[image]

Comment: QGIS or ArcGis solution?

Comment: Ellipses are easy to construct (in Cartesian space, at least), but you've left out the details which would help us to help you: In what spatial reference? With what software? Have you researched heat maps? Please [Edit] the Question.

Comment: Thanks for replying Vince, sorry I should have said, I am using QGIS 3.4.9. I have figured out a solution using the intepolated data and the contours generated from this layer. I can then manually draw a circular string using the shape digitizing toolbar tools, then turn the line into a polygon, which allows me to calculate an area. it seems to work quite well, so ill keep your comments in mind when raising any other questions, thanks again